# How To Iterate Through Every Latitude/Longitude in Java

Tags: java

I'm accessing this API that gives me global weather:

https://callforcode.weather.com/doc/v3-global-weather-notification-headlines/

However, it takes lat/lng as an input parameter, and I need the data for the entire world.

I figure I can loop through every latitude longitude, every 2 latitudes and 2 longitude degrees, giving me a point on the world, every ~120 miles across and roughly 100 degrees north/south, which should give me all the data in 16,200 API calls ((360/2) * (180/2)).

How can I do this effectively in Java?

I'd conceived something like this; but is there a better way of doing this?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 360; i+2){
  var la = i;
  for(int x = 0 x < 180; x+2) {
    var ln = x;
    //call api with lat = i, lng = x;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes that's it ;)

Comment: You're almost definitely going to hit rate limits on that API, not to mention that it will be very time consuming.

Comment: you could optimize it by dividing the space using grid files ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_file ), based on population distribution.

Comment: Think about multithreading also

Comment: why do you need the weather everywhere, don't you just care about where people are?

Comment: In your `for` loops you probable mean `i+=2` and `x+=2`, not `i+2`and `x+2`.

Comment: ah yes ta @ThomasFritsch.

Comment: @depperm And that would be ideal but who am I to arbitrarily pick where I think people are, people are pretty much everywhere

Comment: "people are pretty much everywhere" but not all of them will be using your app and certainly not the same instance. I think you need to re-think your app design if you have the need to cover all of the planet for a user

Comment: Nearly three-fourths of the earth's surface is covered in water. Do you really need to get the weather for the middle of the Pacific Ocean?

Comment: Assuming that when you ask "is there a better way of doing this?" that "better" == "more efficient", I don't think there is enough information to answer this question. You're making alot of requests to the API and that will take awhile. A nested loop itself isn't particularly inefficient for what you're trying to do, but what you are trying to do is likely very inefficient for the use case. What is the use case?

Comment: @shoover the residents of Fiji, Tonga and Hawaii would say yes

Comment: @Zachary use-case is trying to find all severe weather for the globe. this is the only api I've found that does it. Alternative is to query the weather centres of individual countries and deal with the inconsistent formats returned. there was one other website I found, weather underground but that didn't return useful enough location data in the results

Comment: @Wayneio Those are landmasses, not water.

Comment: @shoover yh but they'll care if there's a storm in the ocean heading their direction :)

Comment: But we don't know the op's use case. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's somewhat of a paradigm shift, but *I would NOT use a nested for-loop for this problem*. In many situations where you are looking at iterating over an entire result set, it is often possible to trim the coverage dramatically without losing much or any effectiveness. **Caching, trimming, prioritizing**... these are the things you need: not a for-loop.

1. Cut sections entirely - maybe you can ignore ocean, maybe you can ignore Antartica and the North Pole (since people there have better ways of checking weather anyway)
2. Change your search frequency based on population density. Maybe northern Canada doesn't need to be checked as thoroughly as Los Angeles or Chicago.
3. Rely on caching in low-usage areas - presumably you can track what areas are actually being used and can then more frequently refresh those sections.

So what you end up with is some sort of weighted caching system that takes into account population density, usage patterns, and other priorities to determine what latitude/longitude coordinates to check and how frequently.
High-level code might look something like this:

```
void executeUpdateSweep(List<CoordinateCacheItem> cacheItems)
{
    for(CoordinateCacheItem item : cacheItems)
    {
        if(shouldRefreshCache(item))
        {
            //call api with lat = item.y , lng = item.x
        }
    }
}

boolean shouldRefreshCache(item)
{
    long ageWeight = calculateAgeWeight(item);//how long since last update?
    long basePopulationWeight = item.getBasePopulationWeight();//how many people (users and non-users) live here?
    long usageWeight = calculateUsageWeight(item);//how much is this item requested?

    return ageWeight + basePopulationWeight + usageWeight > someArbitraryThreshold;
}
```